# Bypassing the normal distribution table

Tags: normal-distribution

Ive been looking around for a while and didnt seem to find this anywhere.  I usually make mistakes when reading values from the normal distribution table. I wanted  to know whether it is possible to calculate the corresponding value without the table, i. E, apply the values of variance and mean to it. Im taking CIE A level in maths. Thx.

Comment: You are asking how to know the values of the Erf function. There is no closed-form solution, but of course you can use plenty of approximation algorithms (including available software) for this.

Comment: But how did they obtain these values in the table? They had to be using some sort of equation. I just need that equation to plug in my data and obtain the answer directly.

Comment: They have used approximation algorithms. There is no closed-formula.